# See if a user is talking in a voice channel with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to see if a user is talking by using discord.py library. Is there a function or code that I can use to do that? Maybe something like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_talking_update(user, prev, cur):
    if cur.is_talking and prev.is_not_talking:
        print("the person is now talking")
    elif prev.is_talking and cur.is_not_talking:
        print("the person is done talking")
```

Comment: Talking is not implemented, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You can't detect if someone is talking in a voice channel. You can only see if they are in a voice channel.